# Thermal vias in Eagle (CAD)

Tags: eaglecad, thermal, via

I'm making a part in Eagle (4.15) for a SOIC-8 package.  There is a thermal pad in the center and I'm trying to add vias stitching the top and bottom pads together.  In the Eagle package editor there are no vias, I can add pads or holes.  Is there a standard way to do this?  I've found some related [questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10146/vias-on-qfn-centre-pad-in-eagle-pcb),  [and this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80642/eagle-cad-thermal-vias), but no answers that help me.

I'm using an old version of eagle (4.15)

Comment: I think the difference between 'vias' and 'pads' is only a matter of terminology and refers to how they are used on the board: either for routing or to solder a thru-hole component. When designing a component footprint there is no difference...

Comment: @brhans, yeah that's right.  My problem is that if I use through hole pads to stick the top and bottom layer together I then end up with a whole bunch of extra pads in my package.  I can try leaving these unconnected and see what happens.

Answer (score 8):

**Use pads.**

You can use an array of pads to create these thermal vias. The difference between pads and vias are that pads always go all the way through, vias can be blind or buried. For thermal vias, you want to go all the way through, so use pads.

If you use holes there will not be an electrical connection through the board, thus minimal thermal conduction. So it's rather pointless and will likely only cause DRC errors related to placing metal (for the thermal pad) too near a drill hole.

Here's an example from my library using pads for thermal vias.

[image: thermal vias]

Just connect each of the pads to the same pin as the ground pad. This makes them of the same net *before* being placed in the layout editor, thus avoiding the pad-to-pad or similar possible DRC errors.

[image]

Comment: So do you leave all those pads (in the package) unconnected when you connect the package to the symbol?  Or do you just make a device with a lot of extra "pins".

Comment: @GeorgeHerold You can add multiple pads to a single pin, just connect all of the pads to the same pin.

Comment: Hmm, OK maybe this is because I have an old version of eagle.  But in the library editor I can only connect one pin to one pad... unless I'm missing some special key combination.

Comment: Ah, no append button? I checked the release notes for versions 4 through 7 and don't see it being added, so I assumed it was in there. It should be in the connect dialog in the part editor.

Comment: Ahh.. what's an append button look like :^)  I've just been reading my manual (always a last resort) It says, "One pin has to be connected to exactly one pad!"  Their exclamation mark, so I assume I'm stuck in this version.  I'll make a bunch of extra pins and stick 'em down with the other power pins.. gotta keep a nice clean schematic.

Comment: Looks [like this](https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/007/973/medium800/manufacturing_device_connectvcc.png?1396846535), in the bottom middle. You might try not connecting them and see if it gives any errors, otherwise, yeah you'll have to kludge in the extra pins.