# Power line between data lines

Tags: pcb-design, signal-integrity, power-integrity

I am finalizing my design which connects a USB Controller ([FT601](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT600Q-FT601Q%20IC%20Datasheet.pdf)) with the FPGA ([MachXO2](https://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=38834)). There is last thing I am not particularly happy about and I would like your feedback on that.

In the following image, the two vias connect 2 supply sources (3.3V and 1.0V respectively) to the IC while the surrounding traces are LVCMOS33 data lines.

[image: Power and data traces]

The PCB is 4 layer stackup, second plane is ground plane. The data traces are 8 mil wide with an impedance of approximately 54Ω. The lines are bidirectional, and both ICs output at 50Ω impedance, so they are matches. Rise/Fall time is 0.8 to 1.2 ns.

The power lines are 7 mil wide. I made them 1 mil shorter to gain a little bit more space between them and the data lines. They are properly decoupled, since I have put the necessary caps exactly on the opposite side. Their length is around 200 mil.

**Question:** Is there a strong possibility that the power supply will affect the data lines or vice versa, resulting in an instability of the IC?

Simulation in Altium with a proper IBIS file reveals a small fluctuation of 30-40 mV of the power lines affected by the data lines.

In case you are wondering I did not place the supply internally of the footprint because is a QFN with a large pad connected to ground so I cannot risk a short-circuit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on impedance of decoupling cap at 300 MHz and ratio to supply/return impedance lines times current during rise /fall time

Comment: Where are your ground connections?

Comment: @ThePhoton Ground connections are to the left behind the pads. I reuse the vias of the heatsink pad which are connected to the ground. It was the topic of my [last question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/436780/heatsink-pad-connected-to-ground-pins).

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I use a 0.47uF and 0.1uF for the 3.3V line and 6.8uF and 0.1uF for the 1.0V line. Supply/return impedance lines are the same width and the current is approximately 4-8 mA (4 from the FPGA, around 8 from the FT if I am not mistaken).

Comment: You should be more concerned with cross-talk between signals, and less about nearby power traces. If I recall correctly, the distance between traces should be 3x of trace width if you want to avoid cross-talk on digital signals. Also, your power traces are too far and too thin, you might have current starvation on your IC, since parallel buses might have substantial spikes in power consumption.

Comment: @Ale..chenski  I use 8 mil for data signals and I maintain a space of about of 18 mil, is the best I can otherwise they will be too long. Impedance of the driver matches which helps and simulations do not reveal significant crosstalk, less than 50 mV. According to datasheet, max current of the IC is roughly 200 mA. 7 mil traces are able to deliver more than 1A and there are multiple power sources around the IC (7 of 3.3V  and 4 of 1.0V) Here I am discussing a very specific situation I am concerned, thanks for the input.

Comment: It doesn't matter how much a trace can deliver, and whether or not there are other pins. What matters is how inductive the trace is, and how much instant current it can deliver to local I/O bank. And you have no bypass cap in close proximity. You have 32+ bit parallel bus, and consider if all lines are switched at once, in under 1 ns, with drive of 8 mA, it is already 256 mA. You better check the MachX guides on how many parallel bits your part can handle, and look at their layout suggestions for power distribution. By not placing the power in inner space you are risking much more than shorts.

Comment: Consider this: your IC delivers dV=3V in 1ns (10e-9). If the pin has 10pF load (5pF for pin/pad and 5pF for trace), I = C dV/dt = 3e-2, or a spike of 30 mA per pin. This can be about 1 A in 1-ns-short spike for the 32-bit bus, so your local power on I/O bank will sag, and drug down other control lines disrupting the entire data protocol. Think about this, and better put a good array of low-ESR caps around solid power rails, not 7 mils wide.

Comment: @Ale..chenski The part in the picture is the FT601, and is the one that (always) causes me trouble. MXO2 is properly integrated, and I have already checked max parallel bits, it is on p. 50, note 4 in the official datasheet: "[...] shall not exceed a maximum of n * 8 mA. “n” is the number of I/O pads between the two consecutive bank VCCIO or GND connections or between the last VCCIO and GND in a bank and the end of a bank.". Essentially 8 mA per I/O if all I/Os of a bank used. Both chips are properly decouplde, I jusy depict the upper layer. On the bottom layer there caps.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Power rails on the FPGA part are configured properly. I have a lot of space there since it as a TQFP-144. The problem, as I described, is with the FT. It is a QFN-76, 8 mil is the max width I can drive and I have a large heatsink pad in the middle of the package, so I need smaller vias which I can't afford.

Comment: As @Ale..chenski said, consider the power ground traces only as inductors because the resonant effects are long wavelength but may be high Q. Let's say 100nH for two 8cm x 0.2mm tracks  and 0.47//0.1uF on 3.3V /100 Ohm https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvxLA.png  the load depends on average DC current. but any step load changes may have ringing.  THis is a guestimate

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks for the response, I have taken what Ale..chenski wrote into account and I am redesigning some parts regarding power supplies.